# Why TransformBlock get different results?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dataflow, tpl-dataflow

Why `TransformBlock` get different results each time it executes?

Expect:

- 1,2,3
- 4,5,6,7,8,9

Result:

- 4,2,3
- 1,5,6,7,8,9
- 1,2,3
- 4,5,6,7,8,9
- 4,2,3
- 1,5,6,7,8,9
- 1,2,3
- 4,5,6,7,8,9
- 1,2,3
- 4,5,6,7,8,9
- 1,5,3
- 4,2,6,7,8,9
- 1,2,3
- 4,5,6,7,8,9
- 5,2,8
- 1,4,6,7,3,9

```
public static TransformBlock<int, string>  tbInt = new TransformBlock<int, string>((i) =>
{
    return i.ToString();
});
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    while (true)
    {
        Task t1 = Task.Run(() => {
            var res = TransformInt(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', res));
        });
        Task t2 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var res = TransformInt(new int[] { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', res));
        });
        Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { t1, t2 });
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
static IEnumerable<string> TransformInt(int[] sources)
{
    foreach (var item in sources)
    {
        tbInt.Post(item);
        yield return tbInt.Receive();
    }
}
```

How can I get expected?

Comment: How about using a separate `TransformBlock<int, string>` inside each `TransformInt` invocation, instead of sharing a single one?

Comment: That's not who TPL Dataflow blocks are used. This question uses blocks as if they were a kind of `ConcurrentQueue` instead of active processing units. Even a `ConcurrentQueue` would produce different results where, because multiple producers are posting data in a *random order*. Blocks are meant to be connected in a pipeline, receiving messages from the previous block and pushing their result to the next, the same way a shell script pipeline works.